# How we can check the information sent to server in a client request?

Tags: client, httprequest

What are the information sent to server in a client request?How can we check those information? I mean can we view those information(Is there any way to check)?

Comment: what exactly do you mean? do you mean on your site, if a person submits a form, can you get to the value of that submission? or do you mean something else? It's very unclear from your question what you're actually looking to find out.

Comment: @Anatoly I want know when a person submits a form, can I get the value of that submission.

Answer (score 0):

The Net panel in [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) is how i usually check both request and response for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value of the submission when you submit a form on a website by writing a script to be called when the form is submitted. For example, you've got a login form. The form consists of login and password fields.

This form makes a POST request to some location, defined in the form's action attribute:

```
<form action="myScript.php">
```

then, in your script, you would need to use the request object to retrieve elements from it and those will be the info that your user submitted.